# Wrote a code emulater says application stopped running

Tags: android-studio

Just wrote this code and they all work fine individually, but now all of the code keeps saying method invocation may produce java NullpointerException such as:

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
<code>
   {   Typeface myFontView = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "alexBrush_regular.tff");
        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        myTextView.setTypeface(myFontView);
    }
    {   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

{   TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
       txt1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(splashActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
        Handler splashHandler = new Handler();
        splashHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
}
```

Every since I've wrote the font code my emulator stops working:

```java
{Typeface myFontView = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), alexBrush_regular.tff");
        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                    myTextView.setTypeface(myFontView);
                }
```

How do I fix this? It works fine if I remove the font code, but the code is working when i create a new project individually

**EDIT:**
Just changed the file name to ttf and now it works but method invocation may produce java NullpointerException still remains

Comment: You're probably going to be (rightly) asked for logcat and the like, but my first guess is `myFontView` is returning NULL. Have you got that file in your assests (and is it meant to be `.tff` and not `.ttf`?)

Comment: Yeah i just changed that and it now works, thanks for pointing it out i rarely check my spelling but the method invocation may produce java NullpointerException still remains

Comment: If it's _may_ produce NPE (as opposed to it _is_ producing an NPE) then this is -- I assume -- warning about the fact that the asset might not be found (either because of a typo, or because the file isn't there).  I guess the answer is something like `if( myFontView != null ) myTextView.setTypeface(myFontView);` so you don't try using a non-existent font.

Answer (score 0):

What is the stacktrace in your log? I suspect that you don't have access to getAssets() passed some code.

Try using:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), alexBrush_regular.tff");
```

**EDIT:**

Name of the asset should be : alexBrush_regular.ttf

Comment: I do have an assets folder, i've created one and put all my fonts in the assets, but my emulators says that my application stopped running and also saying method invocation may produce java NullpointerException.
Here's what the  [Logcat](http://imgur.com/QCy9oEn) says

Comment: Shouldn't the extension name be: .ttf? Seems like a typo to me.

Comment: Yeap it's meant to be ttf.. my mistake sorry, just changed that now it works but it keeps saying method invocation may produce java NullpointerException

Comment: Seems like the error is now different. Your previous logcat shows the error for the typo. Can you provide a new logcat?

Comment: 03-23 17:21:00.942 6159-6186/com.example.simon.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabf65f70

Log cat just shows this

Comment: I infer you are using Marshmallow. That's a known issue that you can track here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357

Comment: I suppose so if you are seeing what you want. If not, you will need to bump your OS version on the device or the emulator to skip this bug.